# no ano passado X ano passado

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Ola,

No texto qual deve ser usado?

**No ano passado** ou **ano passado**!

Exemplo:

> Este ano eles têm estudado mais do que no ano passado.

Posso falar assim?

> Este ano eles têm estudado mais do que ano passado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendo como correto "Este ano eles têm estudado mais **do que no ano passado**", onde "no ano passado" é um adjunto adverbial de tempo.

Já, em seu segundo exemplo:

Este ano eles têm estudado mais **do que ano passado**,  seria aceito na língua falada embora tenha uma estrutura semelhante a:

- Este ano eles têm estudado mais do que meus sobrinhos.

Onde, "meus sobrinhos" não é um adjunto adverbial.

Answer (score 1):

A frase correta a ser usada no texto é Este ano eles têm estudado mais do que **no ano passado**. pois é uma expressão de tempo.
Em relação ao emprego de **do que ano passado**, este será usado apenas quando for sujeito da frase.